# How to make a preview of the edited text in Gwt?

Tags: javascript, gwt

In my application i edit the text in the `GWT` `HTML` widget by clicking the edit button. The new browser window opens with the `ckeditor` to edit the text,
in the ckeditor we can position, align the text and insert images, links also. The edited text should be shown in the page of the parent window like preview.
Here i am setting the edited text from the `ckeditor` to `HTML widget` which can not show like preview, suppose if i have width and height of the edited text which
are larger than the html widget, then html widget will not show properly i.e it truncates or hides the some text. it will show you upto its capability(width, height).
So i want to know that, Is there any widget in the gwt to show the preview?

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If The HTML content from the Ckeditor could be retrieved, you can display a preview using the [HTML](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTML.html) widget.

```
htmlWidget.setHTML(String); // althought the use of SafeHtml wrapper is prefered
```

HTML widget is the equivalent of a div. So if you want to auto adjust the height according to the content you don't have to set explicitly the height of the widget but use the CSS property `height:auto;`

http://jsfiddle.net/34hGu/

Comment: Hello moh, I mentioned that i am using html widget only but the problem is with height and width, Please re-read my query